# Control the data being sent to AppInsight traces

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights, telemetry

Is there a way to control the data being sent to AppInsights traces. As the official documentation says, filetering & preprocessing is way to do. I am not able to get the property(password) from the POST & PUT. As the password is sensitive, i don't want to be sent to App Insights.
Below is  from my traces:

> "Value": "client_id={someguid}&resource={someguid}&username={username}&password={password}&grant_type=password&scope=openid&nca=1;1;login-NonInteractive;False"

```
 public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        var requestTelemetry = telemetry as RequestTelemetry;
        if (requestTelemetry != null && (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == HttpMethod.Post.ToString() || HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == HttpMethod.Put.ToString()))
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream))
            {
                string requestBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
                requestTelemetry.Properties.Add("body", requestBody);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: when you mentioned the property "password", do you want to send the password to application insight, or not send to? can you please provide more details? thanks.

Comment: Yes the password is being over as plain text in the Request Telemetry

Comment: where is your code to send the password? or sent by sdk automatically?

Comment: When the b2cazure is configured to be in Development mode , all the details will be sent over

Comment: In the using sentence, after getting the inputStream, try to replace the password or remove. such as if(requestBody.contains("password")){requestBody="new xxx"}.

Comment: @Andro Is there any update on my answer below?  If you find my answer is useful please accept/upvote it,so that it might help to other community members

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer is currently this is **not supported in `Application Insights`**.

You can look here on how to handle the [Personal Data with Application insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-customer-data)

> Note: If you’re interested in viewing or deleting personal data, please
>   see the [Azure Data Subject Requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/gdpr-dsr-azure) for the GDPR article. If you’re
>   looking for general info about GDPR, see the [GDPR section](https://servicetrust.microsoft.com/ViewPage/GDPRGetStarted) of the
>   Service Trust portal.

For any typical project, *it's not recommended to store/show password as naked (even in the logs)*. **It's Strict violating the privacy**

For your use case, as mentioned by Ivan Yang in the comment. Instead of putting/dumping the whole request body content into the app insight logs, **you should filter out/remove the password**.

```
   public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        var requestTelemetry = telemetry as RequestTelemetry;
        if (requestTelemetry != null && (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == HttpMethod.Post.ToString() || HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == HttpMethod.Put.ToString()))
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream))
            {
                string requestBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
                int startIndex= requestBody.LastIndexOf("&password=");
                int endIndex= requestBody.LastIndexOf("&scope=");
                requestBody = requestBody.Replace(requestBody.Substring(startIndex, (endIndex - startIndex) -1),""); 
                requestTelemetry.Properties.Add("body", requestBody);
            }
        }
    }
```

You can provide your [own feedback here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/357324-application-insights/) if you really want a feature like a turn on/off some fields to be mask/unmask during the logging into app insights

Answer (score 0):

Before pushing data to appinsight we usually serialize our class object. When you are serializing your class object at that time you should ignore your property from serialization. In C# you can use ScriptIgnore attribute of System.Web.Script.Serialization library.

Please go through the below post once.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute?view=netframework-4.8

If scriptignore does not solves your problem, then you can create your own attribute.